# Multilanguage htaccess file (LTD)

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual

I want to have a multi language site. Now, I have 2 domains. The first one is the main domain. That is website.nl. And i have a domain alias, website.org. So the 2 domains share the same public_html folder.

What I want is that:
website.nl will use the file /index.php/$1 and
website.org will use the file /gb/index.php/$1 (So when the url is website.org/test you will use the file /gb/index.php/test (No url redirect)

I found on another topic on stackoverflow the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gb/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But this htaccess file won't work. I will get a 500 error. That's all.

Can someone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules are looping, otherwise the 2 rules will mess with each other and loop indefinitely (e.g. requesting `/foo` will result in `/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php... etc` thus returning 500). You need to add some conditions to stop the looping. Try changing the conditions and rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.org
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gb/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gb/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gb/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```